# Antlr compiles text but always throws an error when there's a whitespace

Tags: antlr

So this is my grammar:

```
grammar Test;

prog: stmt_list;

stmt_list
: stmt_list stmt ';'
| stmt ';'
;

stmt
: assignment
| bind
;

assignment: 'var' IDENTIFIER ('=' | '+=' | '-=' | '*=' | '/=') expression;

type
: IDENTIFIER
| primitiveType
;

primitiveType
: 'int'
| 'float'
| 'string'
| 'bool'
;

expression
: atom
| expression ('*' | '/') expression
| expression ('+' | '-') expression
;

atom
: '(' expression ')'
| IDENTIFIER
| INT
| STRING
;

IDENTIFIER: [A-z_][A-z_0-9]*;


INT: [1-9][0-9]*;
STRING: '"' [A-z] '"';

WS: [\t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

I can compile it with antlr and everything works fine. When I test it with grun it will compile but it throws a "token recognition error" whenever there's a whitespace. For example with this input:

```
var a = b + c;
```

I get:

```
line 1:3 token recognition error at: ' '
line 1:5 token recognition error at: ' '
line 1:7 token recognition error at: ' '
line 1:9 token recognition error at: ' '
line 1:11 token recognition error at: ' '
```

Besides this everything works but it would still be nice if I could get rid of these messages.

Answer (score 3):

You're only putting tabs and line break chars to the hidden channel, not spaces.

Instead of:

```
WS: [\t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

do:

```
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```